# How to perform stencil computations element-wise on a matrix in Theano?

Tags: python, image, numpy, kernel, theano

I have the following blurring kernel I need to apply to every pixel in an RGB image

```
[ 0.0625 0.025 0.375 0.025 0.0625 ]
```

So, the pseudo-code looks something like this in Numpy

```
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        for k in range(3):
            final[i][j][k] = image[i-2][j][k]*0.0625 + \
                             image[i-1][j][k]*0.25 + \
                             image[i][j][k]*0.375 + \
                             image[i+1][j][k]*0.25 + \
                             image[i+2][j][k]*0.0625
```

I've tried searching for a question similar to this but never found these sort of data accesses in the computation.
How do I perform the above function for a Theano tensor matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Conv2D` function for this task. see the reference [here](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/nnet/conv.html#theano.tensor.nnet.conv2d) and may be you also can read the example tutorial [here](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/lenet.html#the-convolution-operator). Notes for this solution:

- Because your kernel is symmetrical, you can ignore `filter_flip` parameter
- Conv2D is using 4D input and kernel shape as parameters, so you need to reshape it first
- Conv2D sum every channel (I think in your case 'k' variable is for RGB right? it's called channel) so you should separate it first

This is my example code, I use simpler kernel here:

```
import numpy as np
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
from theano.tensor.nnet import conv2d

# original image
img = [[[1, 2, 3, 4], #R channel
       [1, 1, 1, 1],  #
       [2, 2, 2, 2]], #

      [[1, 1, 1, 1],  #G channel
       [2, 2, 2, 2],  #
       [1, 2, 3, 4]], #

      [[1, 1, 1, 1],  #B channel
       [1, 2, 3, 4],  #
       [2, 2, 2, 2],]]#

# separate and reshape each channel to 4D 
R = np.asarray([[img[0]]], dtype='float32')
G = np.asarray([[img[1]]], dtype='float32')
B = np.asarray([[img[2]]], dtype='float32')       

# 4D kernel from the original : [1,0,1] 
kernel = np.asarray([[[[1],[0],[1]]]], dtype='float32')

# theano convolution
t_img = T.ftensor4("t_img")
t_kernel = T.ftensor4("t_kernel")
result = conv2d(
            input = t_img,
            filters=t_kernel,
            filter_shape=(1,1,1,3),
            border_mode = 'half')
f = theano.function([t_img,t_kernel],result)

# compute each channel
R = f(R,kernel)
G = f(G,kernel)
B = f(B,kernel)

# reshape again
img = np.asarray([R,G,B])
img = np.reshape(img,(3,3,4))
print img
```

If you have anything to discuss about the code, please comment. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey, so I ran the above code, and I get the following error - `ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged`

Comment: Another error is that 'half' mode in the covolution function isn't implemented - `Exception: Mode half not implemented` - Numpy and Scipy have been installed with the latest updates, but the error persists

Comment: for the second error, try to update your theano my version is 0.8, I'll check the first error

Comment: I noticed that you use nnet's conv2d function that takes 4D tensors. Why not use the `theano.tensor.signal.conv.conv2d` function instead, which takes in 2D matrices and 3D tensors? - (http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/signal/conv.html#theano.tensor.signal.conv.conv2d)

Comment: Looks like `signal.conv.conv2d` doesn't implement 'half' mode. Anyway, I notice now that your R,G,B values are actually only the first three rows of the image, and not channel-wise. To do this, first a `np.rollaxis(img,2)` must be done to shift the color dimension outside, before any further processing. I did this on my image, but I **still** get a faulty output.

Comment: ah yes, sorry, actually I forget that `signal.conv` I have been accustomed to using `nnet.conv2D` :) but yes, with `half` border mode from `nnet.conv2D`, it gives easier way to do convolution from the middle of the kernel

Comment: and sorry again, I have mistaken the axis of the process. you don't need `np.rollaxis()` just "rotate" the kernel by rewrite it like this: `kernel = np.asarray([[[[1],[0],[1]]]], dtype='float32')` I think now it will work like your numpy program. I've update my answer.